# how to stay logged in forever after logging in using Firebase with React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have been stuck on this problem for SEVERAL days.
Basically, I'm trying to make Firebase remember the user so that it stays logged in once logged in.
First block of code it the App component (I cut off some of the necessary code irrelevant to my issue for the first part.) The second block of code if the Form which maps to the Login and Signup.

TypeError: reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.home is not a function

Please let me know how I'm able to accomplish how to stay logged in forever after logging in using Firebase with React Native

```
  export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
    };
  }

   componentDidMount() {
    this.authSubscription = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        user,
      });
    });
  }

   /**
   * Don't forget to stop listening for authentication state changes
   * when the component unmounts.
   */
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.authSubscription();
  }




  render() {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
     if (this.state.loading) return <Loading />; 
     // The user is an Object, so they're logged in
     if (user) return  <Home />; // load home screen and make it route to different places without using actions
     if(!user) return <Login />;
   
      return (
    // The user is null, so they're logged out
        <View style={{"flex": 1}}>
            <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="#002f6c"
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
       {tests}
        </View>
    );
  }
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = firebase.firestore()



  import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StylesSheet, Text, View, TextInput, 
        TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage, Keyboard, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import styles from './formstyles';
import VerseStuff from './Verse'

import * as firebase from "firebase";

import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; 
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Routes from './Routes';

export default class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //this.show = this.show.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }

    btnToChat() {                      //here use arrow  function
        console.log("test");
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');    
    }

    saveData = async() => {
        const {email, password} = this.state;

        // save data with asyncstorage
        let loginDetails = {
            email: email,
            password
        }

        if(this.props.type !== 'Login') {
            try {
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .then(user => { 
                    
                        Actions.newUserOne();
                    });

            } catch(error) {
                errorCode = error.code;
                errorMessage = error.message;

                if(errorCode == 'auth/invalid-password') {
                    alert('Passowrd must be at least 6 characters long!');
                } else {
                    Actions.newUserOne();
                }
            }

        } else if(this.props.type == 'Login') {
            try {
                firebase
                    .auth()
                    .setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
                    .then(function() {

                        return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        Actions.home();
                        // this.btnToChat();
                    });
            } catch (error) {
                errorCode = error.code;
                errorMessage = error.message;

                if(errorCode == 'auth/wrong-password') {
                    alert('You entered the wrong password!');
                } else {
                    Actions.home();
                    // this.btnToChat();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    

    

    render() {
        return (
                <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                                onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
                                placeholder="Email"
                                placeholderTextColor = "#002f6c"
                                selectionColor="fff"
                                onSubmitEdiitng={() => this.password.focus()} />

                    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
                                onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                                placeholder="Password"
                                autoCapitalize="none"
                                secureTextEntry={true}
                                placeholderTextColor = "#002f6c"
                                ref={(input) => this.password = input}/>

                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText} onPress={this.saveData}>
                         {this.props.type}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### about your error

did you set Stack Component of your router flux correctly in your App.js?

something like this in your render function

```
<Router>
    <Stack key="root">
      <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" />
      <Scene key="register" component={Register} title="Register" />
      <Scene key="home" component={Home} />
    </Stack>
  </Router>
```

it seems that router flux can not know your key component

### how to stay login

you need to store boolean flag to `true` in local storage (use AsyncStorage) after you get user id from firebase, and set to `false` if user press logout button (someting like that)

Comment: Yes i did that,  if (this.state.loading) return <Loading />; 
     // The user is an Object, so they're logged in
     if (user) return  <Home />; // load home screen and make it route to different places without using actions -> when I render <Home /> that's when it doesn't recognize the Router for some reason
     if(!user) return <Login />;

Comment: also im not sure what you mean by this: "you need to store boolean flag to true in local storage (use AsyncStorage) after you get user id from firebase, and set to false if user press logout button (someting like that)"

Comment: thank you for your help btw, but it still gives me the same error: TypeError: reactNativeRouterFlux.Actions.home is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e had the same problem, I have a fix but the syntax of V9:
First the perssistence solution: initilize your auth that way:

```
import { initializeAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(firebaseApp, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)});
```

Your login should basically be the same but since you need to use the initialized  auth and not firebase.auth(), it looks like this:

```
if (!rememberMe) {
      console.log("not remembering user");
      return setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence)
        .then(() => {
          signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            .then()
            .catch((error) => {
              const errorCode = error.code;
              console.log("error code: ", errorCode);
              setAuthErrorCode(errorCode);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          setLoginLoading(false);
        });
    } else {
      console.log("remembering user");
      // Sign in the user with email and password
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("signed in!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          setAuthErrorCode(error.code);
        });
    }
```

And that should be in the useEffect of your app:

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```